# [$injector:nomod], [$injector:modulerr] error in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm very new to angular js and following is my code

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="node_modules/angular/angular.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        (function(angular){

            var testAngular = angular.module('testAngular');

            testAngular.controller = ("name_controller", function($scope) {console.log("hello");
                $scope.name = {
                    firstName: "null",
                    lastName: "null",
                    setName: function(fname, lname) {

                        if(fname.trim != "") {
                            this.firstName = fname;
                        }

                        if(lname.trim()!="") {
                            this.lastName = lname;
                        }
                    },
                    getName: function() {
                        var name_object = $scope.name;
                        return name_object.firstName+" "+name_object.lastName;
                    }
                };
            });
        })(window.angular);
    </script>

    <div ng-app="testAngular" ng-controller="name_controller">
        Enter first name: <input type="text" ng-model="name.firstName"><br><br>
        Enter last name: <input type="text" ng-model="name.lastName"><br>
        <br>
        You are entering: {{ name.firstName }}
    </div>
```

Now when I'm trying to run this code I'm getting 2 errors in console as

```
[$injector:nomod]
```

and

```
 [$injector:modulerr]
```

Any idea why exactly this is happening. Some post says I need to include the route module but I'm not using routing any where in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change:

`testAngular.controller = ("name_controller", function($scope) {`

to

`testAngular.controller("name_controller", function($scope) {`

Comment: Great. that works.. Just feeling curious I found the "testAngular.controller = ("name_controller", function($scope) {" way in a post, but what iss wrong with that?

Comment: The controller is a function, that accept name and constructor.
You can read more here https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller
and here https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$controller